# How long it takes to show my framework in cocoapods.org site

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoapods

I released my framework to cocoapods but I can't find it in the website although when search with `pod search guggy` it does appear.

Did I do something wrong or it takes some time until appearing in the site?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out you just have to wait, took it about 1-2 hours.